# Pandas python how to split a DataFrame using another DF as criteria

Tags: python, pandas, split

In reality my DF is huge with a lot more columns & more complex masks, but here's the principle I'm after:

DF A: (all birds)

```
  name            size     location
1 bluebird        small    usa
2 cukoo           medium   germany
3 parrot          large    brazil
```

DF B: (new world birds)

```
  name            size     location
1 bluebird        small    usa
2 parrot          large    brazil
```

I would like to split like this:

A

/ \

B C

df C should be A - B.  Look in A, remove everything that's in B, and the result is C.

I wish this worked: C = A[~B] lolz it doesn't

df C should be the old world birds:

```
  name            size     location
1 cukoo           medium   germany
```

There will be no duplicate rows.

And my data is really complex (for a Sankey diagram!)
So it's not practical to create df C by writing a filter like:
A.location != germany, belgium, egypt ... etc

Comment: Are you splitting off B yourself? Or are A and B arriving fully formed? Is there a subset of columns that will uniquely identify a row?

Comment: I am splitting off B myself, but through four different filters. Probably if I were a code ninja, I could combine them easily, but I'm a noob taking baby steps. There is no subset of columns that will uniquely identify a column.

Comment: Okay, so if you're splitting off B yourself, why not just add an `id` column first? something like `A['id'] = range(len(A))`.

Comment: Then you can use my solution after you split off B.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in the generic case and be pretty quick.

First, add a dummy marker variable to B.

```
In [64]: B['found'] = 1.
```

Do a left merge of A and B, which by default merges on common columns

```
In [65]: C = A.merge(B, how='left')
```

Filter C to just those observations not found in B and drop the marker.

```
In [68]: C = C[pd.isnull(C['found'])].drop('found', axis=1)

In [69]: C
Out[69]: 
    name    size location
1  cukoo  medium  germany
```

Comment: This looks good to me.  I need to keep A, B and C and keep splitting until I get all the way to M! This looks good and generic enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're splitting off `B` yourself, just add an `id` column then use that after you split `B` off. This is simple!

```
A['id'] = range(len(A))

#some code to create B

A_in_B_mask = A.id.isin(B.id)
C = A[-A_in_B_mask]
```

(Edited after OP's comments)

Comment: OP doesn't have `id` column. OP wants to use all columns `(name, size, location, ...)` (treated as one column) in place of `id`.

Comment: How do you know that there is no `id` column?

Comment: Moreover, if OP is the one splitting off B, it's trivial to create an `id` column before that.

Comment: How do you add the same value in `id` column for `(parrot,large,brazil)` in both dataframes ? (OP = Original Poster = person who asked the question)

Comment: Ah, I _am_ splitting off B myself!  This id thing may work. FWIW, my real data (name) contains repeats like: (parrot, large, brazil); (parrot, large, peru).